# Lost All Buddies in Metal Gear Solid V

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am going through all of the side ops in MGSV and on one of the ops eliminating a tank unit Quiet took a lot of fire and was extracted. Now I have no buddies at all available for missions.

**How do I get Quiet and/or other buddies back?**

A message came up during a side-op after the one where Quiet was extracted saying she had left the sick bay, but several side-ops later and still no buddies.

**What do I do?**

Comment: Are they missing entirely when you are on the deployment screen? What happens if you try to call one while out in the field?

Comment: Thank you @IG_42 calling them in the field worked! Put it in an answer and I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: Could I put in an answer?

Comment: @snoozingnewt sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your buddies back from calling them when you are out in the field.